# Spell checker for Visual Studio Code for bash scripts

Tags: visual-studio-code, spell-checker

Is there a spell checker for VS Code for bash scripts? I've tried [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker), but it doesn't work (even after relaunch of Visual Studio Code):

[image]

Or any ideas how to make Code Spell Checker work on bash scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension does work, but it comes with shell script spell checking disabled.  Here's how to enable it:

[image: The ctrl+shift+p menu]

Click on `USER`

[image: The header that contains User and File]

Scroll down to the languages and click on "shellscript" to change it to a check mark.

[image: shellscript with a disabled icon]

[image: shellscript with a check mark (enabled)]

Spell check should work now and you can see it work on the bottom right of your VS Code editor:

[image]